# Writing pings to files batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ping

Im looking for the best way to write two instances of cmd ping commands to 2 seperate text files using a batch file.

Here is what I have but its not writing to the file im wondering why.

```
start cmd /k ping 8.8.8.8 -t >> c:\troubleshoot_connection_google.txt 
start cmd /k ping 192.x.x.x -t >> c:\troubleshoot_connection_gateway.txt
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Write permission to C:\ is restricted in modern windows versions, write to `%TEMP%\the.file` instead

Comment: If executing in serial is ok you can lose the `start cmd /k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your commands, appart from the point that the root folder of the drive is usually not writteable, is when the redirection to the output file is done.

As you have it written, what is being redirected to the file is the output of the start command, but if you need to redirect the output of the ping command, the redirection must be part of the started command

```
start "" "cmd /c ping 8.8.8.8 -t >> c:\troubleshoot_connection_google.txt"
```

Comment: Thank, that's the answer I was looking for.